# Create just one object from an array of objects, to be used in a redux reducer

Tags: javascript, redux

I have an array of objects like

```
[
  {id: example1, count: 2}, {id: example2, count:2}
]
```

which I would like to turn into an object like

```
{
  example1: { id: example1, count: 2},
  example2: { id: example2, count: 2},
}
```

...and so on.

This is supposed to be used in an redux reducer which uses es6 so if something in there is available that is or in lodash.

### Answer:

For clarity, this is what I ended up doing as @james-emanon suggested in his answer. It is of course just a matter of using reduce.

```
        case ActionTypes.FETCH_SNAPSHOTS_SUCCESS:
          let snapshots = action.payload.reduce((p, c) =>
            Object.assign({},
              p, {
                [c.id]: c
              }
            ), {}
          )

          return Object.assign({},
            state, {
              isFetching: false,
              lastUpdated: action.meta.receivedAt
            },
            snapshots
          )
```

Comment: Do you really need this conversion in the reducer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about something like this? (using es6 conventions)

```
// assuming you action will pass an object like this
var a = [
  {id: 'example1', count: 2}, {id: 'example2', count:2}
]


   // snippet from reducer
   case TYPE.SOME_CASE_CONSTANT: 
   let newObj = action.yourArrayofObj
                 .reduce((p,c) => {
                     return {...p, [c.id]: c}
                 }, {})
   return {
     ...state,
     newObj
   }
```

or

```
action.yourArrayofObj
                     .reduce((p,c) => {
                             p[c.id] = c
                             return p 
                    }, {})
```

Comment: Would this incur any performance penalty by instantiating a new object at each iteration in `reduce`? (Versus merely adding properties to an object on each iteration.)

Comment: @this-vidor maybe, but how big is your list? Presumably they'e building a UI and aren't even doing this for 100 elements. Computers are extremely fast... A better question about tradeoffs is if this is more readable or less readable (for someone who is familiar and comfortable with both styles)

Comment: for me, it is a preference. I could have shortened up even more - but I don't like the idea of having to create an outterscope variable to "store" things. Once the function folds over, the objs are garbage collected.  Also, you had to create a memory allocation for the function. I didn't. I think the JS engines are so performant nowadays, you have to be dealing on the order of 10's of thousands of operations to notice much difference.

Comment: @jamesemanon @Merlyn Wouldn't this be O(n!) time complexity? (My concern wasn't memory.) At each iteration the number of properties in the `p` object increases. (That is, there is a second iteration hidden inside the 'spread' operator.) So on the second iteration of `reduce`, we have to iterate over one property to spread `...p`, but on the 100th iteration of `reduce` we have to iterate over 99 properties to spread `...p`.

Comment: I guess there is some value in what you are saying. I modified my original post to include a less stressful return. But, I still believe the js engines are so peformant now, it doesn't matter. Infact, much of my code uses spreads and such - and I can't say I notice any slow down. when jsperf comes back up, be good to test the performance.

Comment: @this-vidor yes, I spoke too soon. I didn't notice that it was copying previous iterations in my quick glance, and thought you might just be worrying about new objects being allocated. I think you're mistaken about it being O(n!) - I think it is actually O(N^2). If your list was size 10, I still wouldn't care, if this turned out to be more "readable". N^2 for 100 is pretty big though, so you do have a point. The reduce version using inline assignment is much better - similar perf (minus the function call overhead) to your solution.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham Yes, you're right! It's O(n^2).

Answer (score 1):

Something like ?

```
  function arrayToObj(array, keyProperty){
    var result = {}

    for (var i = 0, l = array.length; i<l;i++)
        result[array[i][keyProperty]] = array[i];

    return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `example1` and `example2` are supposed to be strings (e.g., `"example1"` and `"example2"`), using `es6` arrow-notation:

```
let arrayToObj = (arr) => {
  let o = {};
  arr.forEach( (x) => o[x.id]=x );
  return o;
};
```

This is just syntactic sugar over [Andrew McCallum's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37758980/5869747)